# What is the difference between DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE and Raise Notice/Alert

Tags: database, plpgsql

I'm creating a stored procedure in plsql and I have notice something, usually I used "raise notice" to show something in the output console, but I also have some "DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE", so, what's the difference between this two?

For example, the difference between:

```
--Raise Notice way
category_evaluations := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM evaluations_to_consolidate WHERE autoevaluation IS FALSE);
        --Alerts
                raise notice 'Total evaluations to consolidate: %', count_of_evaluations;
        start_date := now();
        --for loop into temp table
        FOR aux_loop IN (SELECT * FROM evaluations_to_consolidate) loop... 



--DBMS way
category_evaluations := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM evaluations_to_consolidate WHERE autoevaluation IS FALSE);
        --Alerts
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total evaluations to consolidate:'||:count_of_evaluations); 
        start_date := now();
        --for loop into temp table
        FOR aux_loop IN (SELECT * FROM evaluations_to_consolidate) loop...
```

Comment: DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE is to print any string, equivalent to printf in C or  System.out.println in java. I have not heard of raise notice from oracle DB perspective so wouldn't be able to comment.

Comment: what is a "raise notice?"  There is a "raise" statement in oracle.  Not clear. Normally, you do not use dbms_output to return output from a procedure.  You would return data as an OUT parameter, then let the caller determine how to present.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I've notice that DBMS is in Oracle, and Raise Notice is for PG, sorry and thanks guys!

Comment: There is no `dbms_output` in PL/pgSQL